# Как выбрать первые 10 строк в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Подскажите как организовать поиск. Нужно выводить следующие, либо предыдущие 10 строк. К примеру: последний результат строки закончился id 12, а следующие строки с id 27,28,29.. Т.е нужно как то запоминать последний результат, зная в какую сторону идет поиск, вперед или назад.  Буду очень признателен если поможете.

Comment: Чем не устраивает `LIMIT 0,10`? Для MySql это аналог `TOP 10` из MS SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем не устраивает `LIMIT 0,10`? Для MySql это аналог `TOP 10` из MS SQL.

```
SELECT
  `ID`,
  `TIMESTAMP_X`,
  `LOGIN`,
  `PASSWORD`,
  `CHECKWORD`,
  `ACTIVE`,
  `NAME`
FROM `b_user`
WHERE 1 = 1
AND id > 5
LIMIT 0, 2;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы спрашиваете также не только десять "следующих" строк, но и "десять предыщущих". Тут вам нужно просто поменять направление при помощи `ORDER BY`, т.к. отрицательные значения в LIMIT нельзя использовать.

```
SELECT
  `ID`,
  `TIMESTAMP_X`,
  `LOGIN`,
  `PASSWORD`,
  `CHECKWORD`,
  `ACTIVE`,
  `NAME`
FROM `b_user`
WHERE 1 = 1
AND id < 7
ORDER BY `ID` DESC
LIMIT 0, 2;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ORDER BY кстати надо всегда указывать - без него SQL не гарантирует порядок строк. то, что строки иногда выдаются по ID - случайное совпадение

Comment: @PashaPash кстати, да, хорошее напоминание. Если топикстартеру важен именно порядок - то нужно указать по каким столбцам сортировать.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Пойду прикручивать =))